# Detecting a swipe to a non-existent element in ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, swipe, motionevent

I have a `ViewPager`, which has `ListView`s in the rear `Fragment`s and I want to intercept a swipe gesture over an item within the `ListView`, if it's moving in the opposite direction other `ViewPager` items are.

Example:
Let's assume that all the other `Fragments` in within the `ViewPager` are on our left already and I try to swipe to the next element (i.e. swipe right to left). Since we're already on the last element, nothing will happen - I want to know when such a move occurs and over which item in the `ListView`.

I've tried intercepting a `MotionEvent` through overriding `onInterceptTouchEvent` in the `ViewPager` class, but ended with the `ListView`'s animations getting buggy instead (the hover-flash wouldn't disappear), and thought myself if that's even the right way to do such a thing.

Is there a feasible way to do this without rewriting whole touch event handling?